# How to avoid namespace leaks?

Tags: packages, scoping

Below is a toy package that illustrates what I mean by "namespace leaks".

```
(* /tmp/bug_or_feature.m *)

Begin["bugOrFeature`"];

ClearAll[foo, makeFoo];

makeFoo[] := Module[{foo},
  foo[] := "BUG OR FEATURE?";
  foo
];

foo = makeFoo[]; (*!*)

End[];
```

The function `` bugOrFeature`makeFoo `` creates a function inside a `Module`'s lexical scope, and returns it.  This function (i.e. `` bugOrFeature`makeFoo ``) is used to create the function `` bugOrFeature`foo ``.

One can `Get` this package repeatedly, without affecting the `` Global` `` namespace:

```
Get["/tmp/bug_or_feature.m"]; Names["Global`*"]
(* {} *)

Get["/tmp/bug_or_feature.m"]; Names["Global`*"]
(* {} *)
```

This stops being the case, however, if one introduces the symbol `foo` in the `` Global` `` namespace:

```
Global`foo = 0; Names["Global`*"]
(* {foo} *)

Get["/tmp/bug_or_feature.m"]; Names["Global`*"]
(* {foo, foo$551} *)
```

Note that now, after evaluating the `Get` expression, there's an additional item in the `` Global` `` namespace, namely `foo$551`.

What's really troubling, however, is that `` Global`foo `` got overwritten during the last evaluation of the `Get` expression:

```
Global`foo
(* foo$551 *)
```

(The line marked with `(*!*)` in the code for `/tmp/bug_or_feature.m` is the culprit, AFAICT.)

> What can one do to prevent code in one namespace from inadvertently overwritting symbols in another namespace?

Also,

> Is the behavior illustrated above a bug or a feature?

Comment: Look at [`BeginPackage`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BeginPackage.html)

Comment: + ``Begin["`Private`"]`` to create ``Package`Private`foo`` when the ``Global`foo`` is screened by `BeginPackage`.

Comment: So the answer is, do what is the standard way to write a package.

Comment: related: [**75333**](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/75333/5478)  and [**43629**](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/43629/5478)

Answer (score 2):

Try something like:

```
System`Private`NewContextPath[{"System`"}]

BeginPackage["bugOrFeature`"]

yourSymbol::usage

Begin["`Private`"]

yourImplementation

End[]

EndPackage[]

System`Private`RestoreContextPath[]
```

Comment: I'm glad that many of undocumented functions' examples are shown lately but a word of explanation would be nice :)