# How to create a GUI notebook that loads at run time?

Tags: programming, user-interface

I am looking to create a Dynamic interface in a notebook that will load itself from one or more packages at run time when it is opened. The interface also uses DockedCells, which also must load content at run time.

I have the following issues:

- I would like to avoid rebuilding the notebook when the packages are updated
- Need to prevent function evaluation when creating the notebook
- Dynamic calls in DockedCells slow down the interface dramatically such that it is unresponsive to user actions like moving the window
- If multiple copies of the notebook are opened they can not share variables

What is a robust method to accomplish this?

Comment: So how is the 4th point solved exactly? Or 3rd?

Comment: p.s. 1. `Dynamic[ui]` with/wo [**WRI versioning style**](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/116249/5478).

Comment: 2. [**Create a notebook and save it without prompting Dynamics**](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/109651/5478)

Comment: 3. discussed in closely related: [**Notebook's WindowSize interference with contents' Dynamic ImageSizes**](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/61659/5478)

Comment: 4. [**How does $CellContext` work?**](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/102391/5478)

Comment: @Kuba 3rd point: My early attempts were to set `DockedCells->Dynamic[dockedCellFunction]`. This gave the unresponsive behavior. The answer below sets it when the Initialization runs.

Comment: @Kuba 4th point: I hope that Dynamic is taking care of this correctly for me, but that is a big part of the reason I am soliciting suggestions - I want to make sure I am not missing something. All my testing seems to say that it works correctly. I am not sure that the `CellContext->Notebook` is strictly necessary.

Comment: I think it depends. A minimal example of working GUI would be nice. If you define your GUI variables in a package and don't use DynamicModule then they may or may not be shared (depeding of the state of the $Context while creating GUI)

Comment: @Kuba Typically my contentFunction would be wrapped in `DynamicModule`. To pass variables between the contentFunction and the `DockedCells` I use `TaggingRules` for the `EvaluationNotebook`. I figured that if no one points out any major flaws with the approach in my answer I would post a more functional working GUI with a tabbed interface.

Comment: @Kuba Thanks for the links. I will need to study the ones on Dynamic

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the method I have worked out after a lot of trial and error, but I would appreciate any suggestions for improvements to it.

I use a function with the `HoldAll` attribute to input the names of symbols from my package that contain all the content that the interface notebook needs to load. At run time I use the `Initialization` option of `DynamicModule` to load the package and set the notebook content.

If the `DockedCells` option is not specified in the notebook at build time then it doesn't display when I specify it with `SetOptions` (it will display if the user moves the window), so I specify a blank `Cell` at build time.

To prevent evaluating the `Initialization` option when `CreateDocument` builds the notebook, I first set the $`FrontEnd` option `DynamicUpdating` to `False`, save and close the notebook, and then reset it to `Automatic`.

The code for a minimal package that implements this is:

```
(* ::Package:: *)

BeginPackage["RunTimeGUIMinimal`"]

RunTimeGUIMinimal::usage = "RunTimeGUIMinimal[packages_List, titleFunction_Symbol, contentFunction_Symbol, tabFunction_Symbol]  "

GUITitle::usage = "GUITitle  "
GUIContent::usage = "GUIContent  "
GUIDockedCell::usage = "GUITabList  "


Begin["`Private`"]
(* Implementation of the package *)


SetAttributes[RunTimeGUIMinimal, HoldAll]


RunTimeGUIMinimal[packages_List, titleFunction_Symbol, contentFunction_Symbol, dockedCellFunction_Symbol] := 
    CreateDocument[{
        DynamicModule[{content},
            Dynamic[content[]],
            Initialization:>(
                Map[Needs, packages];

                (* set the WindowTitle *)
                SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], WindowTitle -> First@Flatten@{titleFunction}];

                (* set the DockedCells to their normal state *)
                SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], DockedCells -> dockedCellFunction];

                (* set the content *)
                content[] = contentFunction;
            ),
            UnsavedVariables:>{content}
        ]
        },
        (* set DockedCells to a blank Cell which will be replaced with SetOptions runs in Initialization. If this is not present, the DockedCells don't display until the user moves the window. *)
        DockedCells -> {Cell[BoxData[ToBoxes[""]], "DockedCell"]},
        Saveable -> False, 
        Selectable -> False, 
        ScreenStyleEnvironment -> "Working", 
        (* set the WindowTitle to the value of titleFunction at build time. This will be overwritten by the current package value at run time in the Initialization *)
        WindowTitle -> First@Flatten@{titleFunction}, 
        WindowElements -> {
            "VerticalScrollBar", 
            "HorizontalScrollBar", 
            "StatusArea"
        },
        CellContext->Notebook
    ]


GUITitle = "My Program"


GUIContent = TextCell["Some Dynamic content","Text"]


GUIDockedCell = Cell["A Docked Cell","Text"]


End[]

EndPackage[]
```

The commands to build the notebook are:

```
Needs["RunTimeGUIMinimal`"]

SetOptions[$FrontEnd, DynamicUpdating -> False]

nb = RunTimeGUIMinimal[{"RunTimeGUIMinimal`"}, GUITitle, GUIContent, 
   GUIDockedCell];

NotebookSave[nb, 
 FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[], "RunTimeGUIMinimal"}]]

NotebookClose[nb]

SetOptions[$FrontEnd, DynamicUpdating -> Automatic]

NotebookOpen[
  FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[], "RunTimeGUIMinimal.nb"}]];
```

Inspecting the notebook code shows that the functions remain unevaluated. The package functions `GUITitle`, `GUIContent` and `GUIDockedCell` can be modified and when the notebook is opened again (after a quit) it reflects the changes.

Comment: @Kuba Thanks for the cleanup.

Comment: Since it is created only once you can use `Refresh[..., None]` in a docked cell. Or `SingleEvaluation->True]`.

Comment: @Kuba Good idea, thanks.