# What makes a function ticklish?

Tags: front-end, dynamic, system

The [Advanced Dynamic Functionality tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/AdvancedDynamicFunctionality.html) informally describes a **ticklish function** as follows:

> Every time you evaluate `RandomReal[]`, you get a different answer, and you might think that `Dynamic[RandomReal[]]` should therefore constantly update itself as fast as possible. But this would normally not be useful, and would in fact have negative consequences for a number of algorithms that use randomness internally[...]
>
> For this reason, `RandomReal[]` is not "ticklish", in the sense that it does not trigger updates[...]
>
> The function `Clock` is intended specifically as a time‐based function that *is* ticklish.

How to tell if a function is ticklish? What makes it such?

Naturally, it's easy to see that `Clock[]` is ticklish, as is another function that evaluates `Clock[]`, even if it discards the intermediate result. Thus ticklishness in not a property of the function's symbol (this rules out an attribute, option, or a list of predefined ticklish function heads):

```
MyClock[]:=Clock[];
MyDateString[]:=(Clock[]; DateString[]);
```

then

```
Dynamic[Clock[]]
Dynamic[MyClock[]]
Dynamic[MyDateString[]]
Dynamic[DateString[]]
```

The first three output cells update dynamically, while the fourth does not. How do they know they need to update? At the first sight, there *are* differences in the box form of the last two output cells:

```
Cell[BoxData[
 DynamicBox[ToBoxes[
   $CellContext`MyDateString[], StandardForm],
  ImageSizeCache->{141., {1., 10.}}]], "Output",
 CellLabel->"Out[131]="]

Cell[BoxData[
 DynamicBox[ToBoxes[
   DateString[], StandardForm],
  ImageSizeCache->{141., {1., 10.}}]], "Output",
 CellLabel->"Out[132]="]
```

but that *aha!* was a total flop, as removing the `$CellContext` from the first cell of the two did not make it non-ticklish, while adding it to the second simply broke its display red with a peculiar error message

```
DateString::shdw: Symbol DateString appears in multiple contexts {Notebook$$18$101847`,System`}; definitions in context Notebook$$18$101847` may shadow or be shadowed by other definitions.
```

- (*caveat scrutor*: `` System`DateString `` seemed to have disappeared after that, so I had to restart the kernel to proceed at this point, even though I Remove[]d the definition in the `` Notebook$$18$101847`​ `` context; you may not want to repeat the experiment and simply take my word for it at this point.)

And in fact, simply writing the explicit box form into the notebook

```
NotebookWrite[EvaluationNotebook[],
  Cell[BoxData[ToBoxes[Dynamic[MyDateString[]]]], "Output"]]
```

generates a self-updating cell.

So what does make a function ticklish?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I should emphasize that, due to limited documentation, this is only an educated guess. Additionally, any computer science term (e.g. tree) I use is not strict as I have no CS/IT background.

#### Shortly

> So what does make a function ticklish?

Its dependency tree. If it contains a ticklish function it will be ticklish. (Roughly)

Which functions are ticklish by design? I am not aware of any documentation about that.

#### ?

When should `Dynamic` be updated? It depends on its argument and options (`TrackedSymbols`, `UpdateInterval`).

The argument's dependencies (with respect to `TrackedSymbols`) are used to build a tree of symbols that should trigger that `Dynamic` object updates, together with scheduled updates governed by 'ticklish' functions and `UpdateInterval`.

Then, when any of those symbols changes, or when 'the time comes' for scheduled updates, the Kernel tells the FrontEnd to udpdate a specific `DynamicObject`.

#### Further reading

- You can find more information in

  AdvancedDynamicFunctionality / Automatic Updates of Dynamic Objects

  > tutorial/AdvancedDynamicFunctionality#440620996 (*help browser link*)
- You can also monitor, to some extent, information flow, between the Kernel and the FrontEnd, with LinkSnooper:

  [How to set up LinkSnooper for monitoring FrontEnd--Kernel communication?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/66070/5478)
- Yes `$CellContext` has nothing to do with it.

  By creating `` $CellContext`DateString[] `` it is parsed to `` Global`DateString[] ``, which does not exist and is conflicting with `` System`DateString ``, see more in:

  [How does $CellContext` work?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/73540/5478)

Comment: Interesting, thanks. I thought about the snooper, but it's a deluge. I'll set up a slower `Clock[]` and play with it perhaps. Thanks for reminding me that `$CellContext` is purely a symbolic placeholder, I forgot about it. So your take is that there *is* a  list of known ticklish functions, and an expression is ticklish if it's body references another ticklish symbol, and the grounding of this recursion is still in a manifest list of internal ticklish functions. Am I understanding you correctly?

Comment: @kkm If I understood you correctly, yes, that is what I mean.

Comment: BTW, MMA 11.3 came with a preset link snooper, you no longer need to set it up, just select from the list available kernels.

Comment: @kkm wow, wasn't aware of that, thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, @Kuba. I'll wait a couple days to see if someone comes up with a definitive confirmation that this is indeed the case before checking your answer, but this is a good working hypothesis that explains the behavior I see. By the way, strictly speaking, the dependency "tree" is likely  a DAG, not a tree; the way I'd normally go about it is build the pairs of immediate dependency edges then topo-sort them, otherwise I'd risk the tree growing both O(n²) in space and time.

Comment: “wasn't aware of that, thanks” – my pleasure! This community is awesome! :)